# Error after inital (dualboot with windows 10) installation

Tags: dual-boot

I had found an old computer that I wasn't using anymore and didn't have any important data on it, so I thought i would install ubuntu on it. After going through the installation, and removing the installation medium as instructed, the computer would return an error stating that no bootable device was plugged in. I know there is a hard drive urged in and even if the windows installation broke, the ubuntu one should still work. For some context, I created an unallocated space on the drive that I selected ubuntu to install on. The computer boots, but it can't boot into the internal drive. I installed it on a new partition, incase ubuntu broke something. Then I could use a restore point to restore the computer. Unfortunately, with even the recovory partition nuked, I have no choice but to either reinstall windows, find someway to access the restore point, or to try installing Ubuntu again.

Edit: I am using an HP EliteBook 840, with a broken battery. Due to this, the device was kept on the power cable. Plugging in an external boot device does not work either. The error itself is error 3F0.